# Confirm delete with popup window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a .php file that delete database rows with a popup window that confirm  the action.
I know that are a dozen of examples, but after meany tries do to that I was not able do that, because I haven't knowledge about javacript. 
After some researches I found this([link](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/)) example source code github [link](https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm).

Here is a simplified code that I have managed to "create", but I only get the popup windows when I click on delete action of Item I on the other buttons the action is executed immediately. Could someone help me with this?!

```
<title>Title</title>

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.confirm.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <table class="table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-3">#</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1">Name</th>
                <th class="col-lg-8">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Item 1</td>
                <td><a id="simpleConfirm" href="index.php?action=delete&id=1" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Item 2</td>
                <td><a id="simpleConfirm" href="index.php?action=delete&id=2" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Item 3</td>
                <td><a id="simpleConfirm" href="index.php?action=delete&id=3" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <script>
        $("#simpleConfirm").confirm();
    </script>

</div>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Use a class instead.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use links to delete things as some browsers follow all the links on a page to speed up browsing, or in case a search engine/crawler follows all the links. Use buttons or image buttons instead to trigger the delete behaviour

Comment: @klaus-veliu, were any of our responses helpful? Thanks!

Comment: The solution is here. http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/481231/how-to-get-a-variable-value-from-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

firstly, to use the jquery selector `$("#id")` you will need to make sure the ID's of your html elements are unique. Next, I assume you are looking for a pop up box that will prompt the user whether they would like to delete the specified record/s.

You can do something like this

```
$("#simpleConfirm").click(function(){
    var check = confirm("Please confirm that you want to delete the record?");

    if (check) {
        // insert code to delete record
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I should have told before that I have no knowledge about javascipt. I am giving a full example of my case in this [link][1]
The idea is to make appear the popup window if I click on Delete (item II and III).
Many of you may suggest to use the confirm funcion in Javascript but that is not a solution because modern browsers block that kind of popup if it is used frequently on the page.

  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pa9bc603ltmpktg/confirmdelete.zip

Comment: If its starting from the beginning, I would suggest visiting [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) - at w3 schools, you can get up to speed in both javascript and jquery. in my code I used jquery to identify the element and the code in function is javascript. its that easy!!
also, I would suggest using '<input>' tags of type button.

Answer (score 0):

An ID can only be used once on a page. To target several like elements, rewrite using classes instead of IDs. Also, remember to add your confirmation "question" string to the parameter of `confirm`, and to follow it with your conditional code.

```
<td><a class="simpleConfirm" href="index.php?action=delete&id=1" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a></td>

var confirmed = $('.simpleConfirm').confirm('Are you sure?');
if(confirmed) { 
  /* do something when user clicks 'ok' */ 
} else {
 /* optionally do something else when user clicks 'cancel' */ 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm